# ffmpeg - Ubuntu - Covert mkv to mp4 and hard sub

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

basicly i have 500+ mkv files that i need converting to mp4 they all have ASS subs in side the mkv files, but the video player that i need the mp4 to play have no soft sub option so i need the subs hardsubbed to the mp4 file

i have tired so many diffrent options

the closest ive got is this

```
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf subtitles=${f%.mkv} -acodec copy anime2/"${f%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

error i get is this

```
 Unable to find a suitable output format for 'Bleach'
Bleach: Invalid argument
```

bleach is part of the file name but the full file name is [horriblesubs] bleach - ep number [720].mkv

I would prefer a batch or loop option as doing one by one will take to long

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

```
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -an -codec:s ass "$f.ass"; done
```

removes the ass file from the mkv

```
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf ass="$f.ass"  anime2/"${f%.mkv}.mp4";  done
```

Converts the .mkv with separated ass file to mp4 and hardsubs it.